# Управление групповыми политиками

Tags: windows, администрирование

Здравствуйте! Мне необходимо ограничить доступ в интернет на нескольких машинах, используя управление групповыми политиками на контроллере домена Win 2008r2. Создал объект групповой политики, добавил группу компьютеров в область действия политики, связал объект с доменом.

Но вот не могу найти среди параметров тот, который бы ограничивал доступ к интернету на этих компьютерах. Нашел только следующее:

"Запрет использования общего интернет-подключения в DNS-домене"

Путь размещения параметров: Конфигурация компьютера/Шаблоны администрирования/Сеть/Сетевые подключения. Поддерживается: Только для операционных систем Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Windows XP и Windows 2000 с пакетом обновления 1.

Но это не подходит, т.к. используется Windows 7. И не уверен, что это то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Ограничить или запереть на все 100% ?

Answer (score 2):

Лучше ограничивать доступ в интернет на маршрутизаторе, а не политиками. Если всё-же хотите политиками, то есть два варианта:

- прописать в политиках несуществующий прокси-сервер
- прописать в политиках запрещающие настройки Windows Firewall

Comment: либо, если это одна локалка можно дать левый дейтвей - у человека будет Network is unreachable

Comment: Если только для нескольких машин (не больше 5-ти), то да можно ACL`ами на роутере... Более гибкий, и, как мне кажется, более правильный вариант - использование прокси-серверов (любого типа, но в данном случае - MS, чтоб прикрутить к AD, однако теперь есть и linux решения такого плана). Только ради бога, не лепите проксю на машину с доменом.